# How to check if column contains substring or multiple words?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, plpgsql

In Postgresql version 15, I have two tables which potentially may contain same objects. In both tables (namely `architecture_permissions` and `experts_conclusion`) I have columns named `object_name`. My tasks are the following:

1. Check if column values are cyrillic or latin. If values are in cyrillic translate them to latin. I'm using such function:

   `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cyrillic_transliterate(p_string text) RETURNS  varying AS $BODY$ SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(translate(lower($1, 'абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхцэы, 'abvgdeezijklmnoprstufхcey'), 'ж','zh'),'ч', 'ch'), 'ш', 'sh'), 'щ', 'shh'), 'ъ', ''), 'ю, 'yu'), 'я', 'ya'), 'ь', ''); $BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE COST 100;`
2. check which tables columns has longer value, then check if longer column contains values of smaller one. E.g.:

In `architecture_permissions` table, column `object_name` has value:

> Жиззах шаҳар Иттифоқ маҳалласи Лойиҳадаги кўчаси ҳудудида жойлашган
> фуқаро Хайитбаев Ойбек Ўрал ўғлига тегишли нонвойхона биносини
> 2-қаватли қилиб реконструкция  қилиш.

transliterated from `cyrillic_transliterate` function gives such result:

> jizzaх shahar ittifoq mahallasi loyihadagi ko'chasi ҳududida
> joylashgan fuqaro хajitbaev oybek o'ral o'g'liga tegishli nonvoyхona
> binosini 2-qavatli qilib rekonstruksiya  qilish

In `experts_conclusion` table, column `object_name` has value:

> Xajitbaevga nonvoyxonasini rekonstruksiya qilish uchun

Words may be in different order, misspelled or have suffixes or prefixes:

> хajitbaev -> Xajitbaevga
> nonvoyхona -> nonvoyxonasini
> rekonstruksiya -> rekonstuksiya

If there are multiple words more than 3 that match longer column join them. E.g:

> jizzaх shahar ittifoq mahallasi loyihadagi ko'chasi ҳududida
> joylashgan fuqaro хajitbaev oybek o'ral o'g'liga tegishli nonvoyхona
> binosini 2-qavatli qilib rekonstruksiya  qilish

contains words:

> Xajitbaev, nonvoyxona, rekonstruksiya, qilish

then join this two records.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? If you want help with the "Tricky part" then I'd suggest removing the rest (the transliteration seems irrelevant) and be specific (which is it - "3 or 4"?). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644132/11810946) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74681721/11810946) may help. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/11810946) for guidance re how to ask. Also it's unclear why you have added a go tag?

Comment: @Brits thank you, sorry if question is confussing. The essential part is to join two tables on records where those multiple words are included in text which are they being compared to.

Comment: Split object_name to words by ``regexp_split_to_table`` and try use ``pg_trgm.similarity`` method for words comparison.

Comment: *"Words may be in different order, misspelled or have suffixes or prefixes"* - with this fuzzy definition, anything can match. You have to be a lot more specific. And trim the noise from your core question.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be fixed/optimized:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cyrillic_transliterate(p_string text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
               translate(lower($1)
                       , 'абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхцэыъь'
                       , 'abvgdeezijklmnoprstufхcey')
             , 'ж', 'zh')
             , 'ч', 'ch')
             , 'ш', 'sh')
             , 'щ', 'shh')
             , 'ю', 'yu')
             , 'я', 'ya');
$func$;
```

[`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.40.1.1.1) can replace characters with *nothing*, like demonstrated.

About `PARALLEL SAFE`:

- [When to mark functions as PARALLEL RESTRICTED vs PARALLEL SAFE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/251274/3684)

**The rest of the question is currently too fuzzy.**